# Cells not appearing in UICollectionView?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionViewController in a storyboard which has been linked to a file called `XCollectionViewController.swift` which is a subclass of `UICollectionViewController`.

My code is as follows:

```
super.viewDidLoad()
    // Register cell classes
    self.collectionView!.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
}


    override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    //#warning Incomplete method implementation -- Return the number of sections
    return 4
}


override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    //#warning Incomplete method implementation -- Return the number of items in the section
    return 10
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UICollectionViewCell

    // Configure the cell

    return cell
}
```

I have the reuse identifier for the cell set as it is named in the file.

On run I can see the background of the CollectionView, but not the 40 Cells I should be seeing. What is wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply delete this line in `viewDidLoad` method would show your 40 cells.

```
self.collectionView!.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
```

Comment: Why? And how do I refer to a reuse identifier if I haven't defined any?

Comment: @LukasKalinski You can set reuse identifier in your storyboard.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I just realized I misinterpreted your answer. Sorry!